# How to add a custom social media icon to the Twenty Twenty theme?

Tags: wordpress, svg

I made a child theme of Twenty Twenty and need to add an Apple Music logo to the social media icons.

I added a folder called classes and copied the class-twentytwenty-svg-icons.php to the child theme.

The icon doesn't show for the link to which I added the applemusic title attribute in the Social menu. Any ideas? I got the SVG definition from an icon downloaded from the Apple Music website.

I added the code below among the other social media icon definitions:

```html
  'applemusic'     => '<svg width=24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M28.187,7.195c-0.001-0.867-0.076-1.728-0.282-2.574c-0.372-1.536-1.247-2.713-2.561-3.573
 C24.67,0.607,23.93,0.335,23.14,0.193c-0.608-0.109-1.221-0.159-1.838-0.177c-0.048-0.002-0.098-0.009-0.146-0.014H7.032
 c-0.178,0.01-0.356,0.02-0.534,0.03c-0.878,0.05-1.75,0.146-2.575,0.472C2.351,1.126,1.219,2.21,0.555,3.768
 C0.33,4.296,0.212,4.856,0.129,5.423C0.062,5.883,0.024,6.345,0.011,6.81C0.01,6.846,0.002,6.882-0.001,6.918v14.359
 c0.01,0.166,0.019,0.332,0.03,0.498c0.059,0.957,0.181,1.908,0.584,2.787c0.764,1.668,2.041,2.764,3.799,3.291
 c0.495,0.149,1.005,0.22,1.519,0.268c0.651,0.062,1.304,0.072,1.957,0.072c4.319,0,8.638,0,12.957-0.002
 c0.617,0,1.231-0.039,1.844-0.116c0.967-0.124,1.876-0.412,2.697-0.952c0.988-0.65,1.729-1.512,2.208-2.594
 c0.219-0.495,0.344-1.021,0.434-1.555c0.134-0.793,0.163-1.595,0.162-2.397C28.188,16.116,28.191,11.656,28.187,7.195
  M20.642,11.882c0,2.237,0.001,4.474-0.001,6.71c0,0.49-0.067,0.971-0.285,1.417c-0.339,0.694-0.894,1.13-1.63,1.339
 c-0.41,0.117-0.829,0.184-1.256,0.203c-1.118,0.053-2.084-0.705-2.284-1.804c-0.166-0.907,0.268-1.907,1.221-2.374
 c0.38-0.188,0.786-0.293,1.196-0.381c0.444-0.096,0.89-0.18,1.332-0.282c0.322-0.074,0.537-0.271,0.6-0.606
 c0.015-0.074,0.021-0.151,0.021-0.227c0.001-2.132,0.001-4.263-0.001-6.394c0-0.073-0.012-0.147-0.03-0.217
 c-0.046-0.177-0.175-0.285-0.357-0.275c-0.188,0.011-0.373,0.041-0.558,0.078c-0.893,0.176-1.785,0.357-2.677,0.537
 c-0.911,0.183-1.822,0.368-2.734,0.552c-0.538,0.109-1.076,0.217-1.614,0.326c-0.019,0.004-0.038,0.01-0.056,0.015
 c-0.325,0.09-0.443,0.239-0.458,0.575c-0.002,0.051-0.001,0.102-0.001,0.154c-0.001,3.056,0,6.113-0.002,9.168
 c0,0.494-0.055,0.982-0.253,1.441c-0.327,0.754-0.905,1.223-1.685,1.45c-0.412,0.119-0.835,0.187-1.263,0.202
 c-1.126,0.042-2.061-0.706-2.254-1.814c-0.167-0.955,0.27-1.98,1.354-2.439c0.419-0.176,0.859-0.273,1.301-0.365
 c0.337-0.071,0.675-0.135,1.011-0.207c0.449-0.098,0.684-0.38,0.703-0.839c0.002-0.06,0.001-0.117,0.001-0.177
 c0-3.477,0-6.955,0.002-10.432c0-0.145,0.015-0.294,0.049-0.435c0.082-0.335,0.321-0.526,0.641-0.609
 c0.3-0.078,0.605-0.132,0.909-0.194c0.861-0.174,1.722-0.347,2.583-0.52c0.89-0.18,1.779-0.359,2.669-0.539
 c0.786-0.159,1.572-0.32,2.36-0.475c0.258-0.051,0.52-0.103,0.78-0.124c0.364-0.029,0.614,0.2,0.651,0.566
 c0.009,0.087,0.014,0.175,0.014,0.263C20.643,7.394,20.643,9.638,20.642,11.882L20.642,11.882z"/></path></svg>',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a "How-to" on this subject on my [blog](https://henjak.dev/blog/how-to-add-new-icons-to-twentytwenty-theme/). You need to hook into two filters:  twentytwenty_social_icons_map and twentytwenty_svg_icons_social. Place the following snippets inside functions.php in your child theme.

1. To add a new icon you first need to map the icons with it's URLs.

   ```
   /**
    * 1. Map social icons.
    *
    * @hooked twentytwenty_social_icons_map
    *
    * @param array $icons Mapped icons.
    *
    * @return array $icons Newly mapped icons.
    */
   add_filter( 'twentytwenty_social_icons_map', function( $icons ) {
       $icons['applemusic'] = array(
           'apple.com',
           // Add other URLs as needed
       );

       return $icons;
   }, 10, 1 );
   ```
2. Add the SVGs to the social-icons array.

   ```
   /**
    * 2. Add social icons.
    *
    * @hooked twentytwenty_svg_icons_social
    *
    * @param array $icons Registered icons.
    *
    * @return array $icons Newly registered icons.
    */
   add_filter( 'twentytwenty_svg_icons_social', function( $icons ) {
       $icons['applemusic'] = '<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <path d="M28.187,7.195c-0.001-0.867-0.076-1.728-0.282-2.574c-0.372-1.536-1.247-2.713-2.561-3.573
       C24.67,0.607,23.93,0.335,23.14,0.193c-0.608-0.109-1.221-0.159-1.838-0.177c-0.048-0.002-0.098-0.009-0.146-0.014H7.032
       c-0.178,0.01-0.356,0.02-0.534,0.03c-0.878,0.05-1.75,0.146-2.575,0.472C2.351,1.126,1.219,2.21,0.555,3.768
       C0.33,4.296,0.212,4.856,0.129,5.423C0.062,5.883,0.024,6.345,0.011,6.81C0.01,6.846,0.002,6.882-0.001,6.918v14.359
       c0.01,0.166,0.019,0.332,0.03,0.498c0.059,0.957,0.181,1.908,0.584,2.787c0.764,1.668,2.041,2.764,3.799,3.291
       c0.495,0.149,1.005,0.22,1.519,0.268c0.651,0.062,1.304,0.072,1.957,0.072c4.319,0,8.638,0,12.957-0.002
       c0.617,0,1.231-0.039,1.844-0.116c0.967-0.124,1.876-0.412,2.697-0.952c0.988-0.65,1.729-1.512,2.208-2.594
       c0.219-0.495,0.344-1.021,0.434-1.555c0.134-0.793,0.163-1.595,0.162-2.397C28.188,16.116,28.191,11.656,28.187,7.195
       M20.642,11.882c0,2.237,0.001,4.474-0.001,6.71c0,0.49-0.067,0.971-0.285,1.417c-0.339,0.694-0.894,1.13-1.63,1.339
       c-0.41,0.117-0.829,0.184-1.256,0.203c-1.118,0.053-2.084-0.705-2.284-1.804c-0.166-0.907,0.268-1.907,1.221-2.374
       c0.38-0.188,0.786-0.293,1.196-0.381c0.444-0.096,0.89-0.18,1.332-0.282c0.322-0.074,0.537-0.271,0.6-0.606
       c0.015-0.074,0.021-0.151,0.021-0.227c0.001-2.132,0.001-4.263-0.001-6.394c0-0.073-0.012-0.147-0.03-0.217
       c-0.046-0.177-0.175-0.285-0.357-0.275c-0.188,0.011-0.373,0.041-0.558,0.078c-0.893,0.176-1.785,0.357-2.677,0.537
       c-0.911,0.183-1.822,0.368-2.734,0.552c-0.538,0.109-1.076,0.217-1.614,0.326c-0.019,0.004-0.038,0.01-0.056,0.015
       c-0.325,0.09-0.443,0.239-0.458,0.575c-0.002,0.051-0.001,0.102-0.001,0.154c-0.001,3.056,0,6.113-0.002,9.168
       c0,0.494-0.055,0.982-0.253,1.441c-0.327,0.754-0.905,1.223-1.685,1.45c-0.412,0.119-0.835,0.187-1.263,0.202
       c-1.126,0.042-2.061-0.706-2.254-1.814c-0.167-0.955,0.27-1.98,1.354-2.439c0.419-0.176,0.859-0.273,1.301-0.365
       c0.337-0.071,0.675-0.135,1.011-0.207c0.449-0.098,0.684-0.38,0.703-0.839c0.002-0.06,0.001-0.117,0.001-0.177
       c0-3.477,0-6.955,0.002-10.432c0-0.145,0.015-0.294,0.049-0.435c0.082-0.335,0.321-0.526,0.641-0.609
       c0.3-0.078,0.605-0.132,0.909-0.194c0.861-0.174,1.722-0.347,2.583-0.52c0.89-0.18,1.779-0.359,2.669-0.539
       c0.786-0.159,1.572-0.32,2.36-0.475c0.258-0.051,0.52-0.103,0.78-0.124c0.364-0.029,0.614,0.2,0.651,0.566
       c0.009,0.087,0.014,0.175,0.014,0.263C20.643,7.394,20.643,9.638,20.642,11.882L20.642,11.882z"/></svg>';

       return $icons;
   }, 10, 1 );
   ```

[Menu item | Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guyup.png)

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate this

Comment: I’m happy to help!

Comment: @henjak I wanted to review your blog post, as I'm working through this same issue on another theme, but it looks like your SSL expired a couple days ago.

Comment: @whakawaehere Thank you for letting me know about the issue with SSL. You should be able to see the blog post now.

Answer (score -1):

You can use font-awesome icons links using icons 
**Link:** https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/
Than custom editor or text-block add  tag using the icon

Comment: I would use Font Awesome, but I'm trying to use the theme's built in options

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#schedule Try this one icons using theme based icons  Ex. <span class="dashicons dashicons-tag"></span>

Comment: Are you familiar with the way Twenty Twenty handles these in the social menu? This seems like a workaround and not customizing the theme's functionality

Comment: This isn't a solution. It's an alternative. I'm having the same issue.